# Dashboard conception using python/pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas, dashboard

I have to develop a dashboard with 'customisable' indicators and data comming from multiple csv files.
This will be developped with Django. I first look for Django package but did not find any package that could be useful.

But I do not know how to proceed.

I start learning about pandas library and it is pretty cool but one of my issue is that I have to format dashboard following a model.

My idea was to define indicator store in a python model and loop over thi smodel to calculate indicators and produce dashboard.

For example, indicators could be defined as follow:

```
indicators = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'type': 'recruitement',         # header in pivot table
        'label': 'Randomized all, N',   # indicator label
        'value': ['number',],           # indicator expected result format
        'filter': None,                 # indicator filter to apply
        'source': 'crf_ran',            # indicator csv files source for calculating
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'type': 'recruitement',
        'label': 'Sex (Woman), %',
        'value': ['pourcentage',],
        'filter': 'sex == 2',
        'source': 'crf_ran',    
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'type': 'Follow up',
        'label': 'D7 visits: N performed (% performed/expected)',
        'value': ['number','pourcentage',],
        'filter': 'timing == 7',
        'source': 'crf_vis',    
    },
]
```

source data #1 (crf_ran.csv):

```
record_id,country,pat,sex,age,hiv
1,Ivory Coast,CIV-TR-001,2,51,'positive'
2,Ivory Coast,CIV-SM-002,1,33,'negative'
...
```

source data #2 (crf_vis.csv):

```
record_id,pat,timing,date
1,CIV-SM-001,7,15/01/2021
2,CIV-SM-001,14,21/01/2021
...
```

expected output as csv

```
'type',indicator','Total','Ivory Coast','South Africa'
'Recruitement','Randomized all, N',99,51,48
'Recruitement','Sex (Woman), %',72,70,74
'Follow up','D7 visits: N performed (% performed/expected)','10 (90)','6 (100)','3 (75)'
...
```

expected output as xls

```
Report date: 20/07/2021
                                           Total    Ivory Coast   South Africa
Recruitement
Randomized all, N                             99             51             48
Sex (Woman), %                                72             70             74
Follow up
D7 visits: N performed (% performed/expected) 10 (90)         6 (100)        3 (75)
...
```

But using pandas to calculate the second indicator 'Sex (Woman) %' I have used

```
country_grp = df.groupby(['country'])
country_grp['sex'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

and get the following output

```
country       sex
Ivory Coast   1      0.632653
              2      0.367347
South Africa  1      0.509804
              2      0.490196
Name: sex, dtype: float64
```

I also try to use pivot_table like  this:

```
sex_filt = df['sex'] == 2
pivot_count = df[sex_filt].pivot_table(values="pat", index='sex', columns='country', aggfunc=len).rename(index={2:'Sex (Woman), %'})
pivot_count.to_csv('dashboard.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

and get the following result in csv file:

```
"Sex (Woman), %",24,19
```

until now, I did not find how to proceed to code a customizable dashboard...
And maybe I am wrong intended to do it with pandas...

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Plotly-Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/) it uses pandas dataframes underneath to build interactive, customizable dashboards.

Comment: thanks for replying but I've already read about dash, and it is not exactly what I am looking for